# IIS URL Rewrite dosen't trigger whenever URL dosen't have trailing slash

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

The rule I set up is as follows:

```
<rule name="MyRule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="Develop([/]?.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8081{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>
```

The rewrite is successful in cases such as the following:

1. https://mysite/Develop/
2. https://mysite/Develop/Some/Any/Stuff

but it doesn't want to work in the case:

3. https://mysite/Develop

i.e. when the URL doesn't ends with a slash.

I tried also add the following rule but with no success:

```
<rule name="MyRule0" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^Develop$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8081/" />
</rule>
```

I tried in every way but with no success.
How can I make the latter case work as well?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to test your first rule on my side and found that it rewrite from `http://localhost/Develop` to `http://localhost:8081` successfully. You could see my [test result here](https://imgur.com/a/NNfmyyy).

Comment: Thank you Deepak for your reply.
I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely solved thanks to the following rules:

```
<rule name="MyRule0" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^Develop$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/" />
</rule>
<rule name="MyRule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="Develop([/]?.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8081{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>
```